# How to use ECHO with REQUIRE()

Tags: php

I want to echo a variable in a require() function:

```
 define('INT_URL', '/var/www/');
 require(echo INT_URL . 'views/_includes/navbar-wp.php');
```

However, I get `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in line 2`.

Where am I going wrong? Is it not possible to echo variables into statements like this?

Comment: `require(INT_URL . 'views/_includes/navbar-wp.php');`

Comment: You do *not* need to use `echo` there. Why do you need `echo`? What are you trying to print?

Comment: `echo` is for displaying something in the script output. Where did you get the idea you needed it in function arguments? (Before someone corrects me, I know `require` is not really a function.)

Comment: Bonus info : require is not a function so you dont need to use ( and ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this without `echo` you don't need it using `require` function, is already interpreted your constant from php

```
require(INT_URL . 'views/_includes/navbar-wp.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Alessandro gave you the code to fix that error.
The problem is that `echo` pushes the given string to the response output, meaning that the client would receive it in response to their request. However, as you only want to pass it into the `require` language construct, you can remove the echo.